# How does Alexa treat with Meteor or Ajax request?

Tags: ajax, meteor, seo, alexa-internet

I tried Meteor JS framework, it's amazing. 
I plan using it in our company's website.

But I'm warried about this will effect Alexa traffic rank and PV.

How does Alexa treat with Meteor or Ajax request? Will Meteor Framework effect Alexa traffic rank?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes Meteor is awesome! and runs in realtime which is why:

Meteorites randomly fall every once in a while, we need to guess how often they will fall. If they fall in a populated area like in a town in russia, [we can extrapolate how often they would fall anywhere](http://www.alexa.com/help/traffic-learn-more), including the sea, because we can only monitor them in the populated areas for the moment.

While there are many fragments of the original Meteor, when it comes to counting we count the meteors that came by (unique hits) and that's looked at more than the individual fragments (hits).

So in short, using ajax/websockets wont make a difference.

Comment: Thanks. But if a whole website based on ajax request, the webpage will be only visited one time at the beginning. I just wander what is the Alexa's algorithms about this.

Comment: What matters are the unique visits per day so ajax doesn't matter it would be counted as one anyway without ajax